# 2 color linear gradient progress bar only halfway complete

Tags: css, progress, linear-gradients

I am having trouble trying to get a 2 color linear gradient to stop partway, without ending with the second color.

So the idea is to use a linear gradient to show how much bandwidth has been consumed.  I have a starting color, and a color 100% should represent. But when I show only 50% with the linear gradient, the 50% mark is the second color.  It should only be about halfway between the 2 colors, the same color it would be at 50% if the usage was at 100%.

I use this code:

```
background: linear-gradient(-90deg,  #438600, #8fd747);
```

But a 25% and a 75% (for example) would both have #8fd747 at their respective ends.  I need them to end at the color 25% and 75% (respectively) between the two colors in my linear gradient.

I can't imagine it's that hard, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Here is what I am looking for with images:

100%: [image]

50%:  [image]

25%:  [image]

As you can see above, the bars represent the full gradient even when not full.  But in those that are less than 100%, I want the gradient to show the level that would be the gradient for it's specific percentage, as seen in the 100%.  I shouldn't get the full darker color until it actually hits 100%.

Comment: You'll have to reword this. It's impossible to follow, specifically "I need them to end at the color 25% and 75% (respectively) between the two colors in my linear gradient." A small image or 2 might actually help in this case. Be sure to search.

Comment: I searched high and low, and couldn't find any examples to limit the gradient to it's percentage level.

Comment: So...I think you're saying you want the gradient to always look like it does in the 100% sample above. You want to start with no part of that gradient visible and slowly *reveal* it from left to right. ?

Comment: Yes.  And when it is revealed, and less than 100%, I want it to stop at the specified percentage.  Animation is nice, but not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the `background-size` and use multiple background in order to obtain this. The top layer will be a single color gradient that will cover the main gradient and show only the needed part of it:

```css
.progress { 
 height:30px;
 margin:20px;
 background-image: 
  linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc),
  linear-gradient(to left,  #438600 , #8fd747 );
 background-size:var(--p,50%) 100%,100% 100%;
 background-position:right,left;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
</div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:70%">
</div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:30%">
</div>
```

Or you can do it with one gradient and adjust `background-position`:

```css
.progress { 
 height:30px;
 margin:20px;
 background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to left,  #438600 , #8fd747 );
  background-size:100% 100%;
 background-position:var(--p,-200px) 0;
 width:400px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-color:#ccc;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
</div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:-50px;">
</div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:-300px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank @temani Afif, I don't think this is exactly what I want.  Based on what I read in your code, and see in your snippet, there isn't a hard stop in my gradient.  I edited the post to show the images of what I'm getting.

Comment: even with the edit if the percentage is 50%, the 50% point is still the full dark radient.  I made a small change to your code with a [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/pzv8hoLu/).

Comment: Your revised version of your first code is very close.  But i want to stop it at a particular percentage (unless it's 100% of course).  I also want it to go from left to right, gradually getting darker.  Every time I try to edit your code in fiddle, I end up with the same results I started with.  Oh, and I need to define the width in HTML, since it will be dynamically pulled.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick.  THANK YOU!  The animation portion doesn't work, but that's not really a requirement (yet).

Comment: @WillSam don't pay attention :) it's not important when there is no comment with it ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171847/discussion-between-will-sam-and-temani-afif).